# paste together first and last value by group

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a df that looks like this:

```
group sequence link 
90      1      11|S1
90      2      10|S1
90      3      12|10
91      1      9|10
91      2      13|9
93      1      15|20
...
```

How can I store the first and last value of the `link`variable in each group as a new variable?
Desired output is:

```
group sequence link  Key
90      1      11|S1 11|S1, 12|10
90      2      10|S1 11|S1, 12|10
90      3      12|10 11|S1, 12|10
91      1      9|10  9|10, 13|9
91      2      13|9 9|10,13|9
93      1      15|20 
....
```

Comment: Do you have typo in your example, group 92 should still be group 91?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    Key = paste(link[1], link[n()], sep = ", ")
  )
```

Though that wouldn't match your desired output. In your example data frame, you have e.g. the group `91` where there's only 1 value. The above code would give you `9|10` repeatedly both as beginning and end.

If you'd like to only display one value in such cases, you can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    Key = case_when(
      n() > 1 ~ paste(link[1], link[n()], sep = ", "), 
      TRUE ~ as.character(link)
      )
  )
```

Comment: awesome! thank you! for other readers: make sure to use ``dplyr::mutate``.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `arrange()` and `slice()` to find the first/last links in your data. My solution is a lengthier than @arg0naut91's, but is perhaps more intuitive.

Create toy data frame...

```r
df <- data.frame(group=rep(letters,3), # create toy data frame
                 sequence=rep(1:3,26),
                 link=sample(9:13,78,T)) %>% 
  arrange(group,sequence) %>% # arrange data
  group_by(group,link) %>% sample_n(1) %>% # remove any duplicate link values (to create uneven sequence var)
  ungroup() %>% arrange(group,sequence) # arrange again to view
glimpse(df)
```

Find first and last links. Add them as new columns to the data frame.

```r
df <- df %>% arrange(group,link) %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% mutate(link.first=link) %>% # find first link for each group
  select(group,link.first) %>% left_join(df,.) # add to original data frame
df <- df %>% arrange(group,link) %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% mutate(link.last=link) %>% # find last link for each group
  select(group,link.last) %>% left_join(df,.) # add to original data frame

df %>% mutate(key=paste(link.first,link.last,sep=', ')) # paste links to form key

# A tibble: 62 x 6
   group sequence  link link.first link.last key   
   <fct>    <int> <int>      <int>     <int> <chr> 
 1 a            1    10         10        12 10, 12
 2 a            2    12         10        12 10, 12
 3 b            2     9          9        11 9, 11 
 4 b            3    11          9        11 9, 11 
 5 c            1    13          9        13 9, 13 
 6 c            2    12          9        13 9, 13 
 7 c            3     9          9        13 9, 13 
 8 d            1     9          9        13 9, 13 
 9 d            3    13          9        13 9, 13 
10 e            1    11          9        11 9, 11
```

Since I used `sample()` with replacement to generate the data, there may be some `group`'s with only one row (i.e., the same first and last link values), which can be filtered out.

```r
df %>% filter(link.first==link.last)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  group sequence  link link.first link.last
  <fct>    <int> <int>      <int>     <int>
1 k            2     9          9         9
2 z            1     9          9         9

df %>% count(group) %>% filter(n==1)
```

Comment: Thanky for your reply! Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, too. It works fine for groups with few rows (<10) but for groups with more rows it doesn't find the right ``last.link``